# Interceptor and ParametrizedType CDI

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I'm trying to inject a interceptor in my BackingBean, see:

```
@SimpleAsync
@Interceptor
public class SimpleAsyncImpl implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Inject
    ScheduleManager sm;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());


    @AroundInvoke
    public Object callAsync(final InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        logger.fine("Invokingchronous method: " + ctx.getMethod().getName());
        // Schedule 0 seconds from now
        sm.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ctx.proceed();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception from asynchronously invoked method.", e);
                }
            }
        }, 0);

        return null;
    }
}


@InterceptorBinding
@Target(value={ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SimpleAsync {
}
```

Now i have the use in my BackingBean:

```
@Named("acervoVideoDetalheMB")
@ConversationScoped
public class AcervoVideoDetalheMBImpl extends BasicDetailMBImpl<AcervoVideo> {

@SimpleAsync
    private void initEnvioVideo(final Part partVideo, String originalName, final String target) {
}
```

The @SimpleAsync is my interceptor, and as you can see the constructor of AcervoVideoDetalheMBIMpl needs a ParametrizedType, the AcervoVideo bean. In my postConstruct i have the following:

```
   @PostConstruct
        public void postConstruct() {

        try {
        ParameterizedType superClass = (ParameterizedType) getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass();
        Class<Bean> type = (Class<Bean>) superClass
                .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return type.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I got the following error:

```
java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
```

But if i remove the @SimpleAsync annotation everything works fine because i disabled Interceptor.

Comment: Your question's a bit confusing, maybe you can rephrase somethings.  Are you assuming that `getClass()` returns `AcervoVideoDetalheMBImpl` in this case? I suspect you're actually getting the proxy class here.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is. The conditional clause is TRUE when i use Interceptores but FALSE when i remove Interceptores. Why the injection  bean change when i use Interceptores?

Comment: Because the interceptor requires proxy, however a scope like conversation scoped doesn't.

Comment: So, interceptor create another bean ? Why dont use a already created bean. As i Said i need use ParameterizedType to execute some methods

Comment: No, its a proxy to your actual class.  Take a look at proxy as defined in CDI: http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#client_proxies

Comment: But have some problem. The PostConstruct is called a multiple times (more than 5).

Comment: I edited my post with more informations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111956/discussion-between-scientist-and-john-ament).